# search in project feature for gedit

Tags: ubuntu, gedit

i just saw an excellent feature on textmate , search in project, you just type a string and it searches all the files in the project for it.Is there such a thing in Gedit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is exactly what you need : http://oliver.github.com/gedit-file-search/

Answer (score 1):

there are a few options, I use the plugin available here http://my.opera.com/area42/blog/gedit-find-in-files-and-find-in-documents-plugin